# Inserting item into DataGrid

Tags: c#, wpf, wpfdatagrid

I have the following tables:

[image]

I'm using Entity Framework Database First, therefore the following entity class is generated:

```
public partial class Sal1 {
    public string SaleID { get; set; }
    public string ItemID { get; set; }
    public int Quantity { get; set; }
    public decimal Total { get; set; }

    public virtual Item Item { get; set; }
    public virtual Sale Sale { get; set; }
}
```

Then put the Sal1 rows into a datagrid like this:

```
private List<Sal1> saleItems = new List<Sal1>();
...
var query = from sa in db.Sal1
            where sa.SaleID.Equals(tempSale)
            select sa;
foreach(Sal1 si in query) {
    saleItems.Add(si);                    
}
...
dgDetails.ItemsSource = saleItems;
```

But it turns out like this:
[image]

My question is, how should I tweak the query above so that I get the equivalent of the following SQL:

```
select T0.SaleID, T0.ItemID, T1.Name, T0.Quantity, T0.Total 
from Sal1 T0 inner join Item T1 on T0.ItemID = T1.ItemID;
```

Thanks in advance.

---

EDIT: I seem to have found a solution, but I had to do this:

```
var query = from sa in db.Sal1
        where sa.SaleID.Equals(tempSale)
        select new  { sa.SaleID, sa.ItemID, sa.Item.Name, 
            sa.Item.Manufacturer, sa.Quantity, sa.Total };
```

And I had to change the type of saleItems to object.

```
private List<object> saleItems = new List<object>();
```

Is this the best way to do it?

Comment: One more thing (in addition to my answer and comment below): EF has automagically created a class named `Sal1` against your database table with all the table columns as class properties. Therefore doing something like `select sa` in your LINQ query will return a collection of `Sal1` objects because the first part of the query `from sa in db.Sal` has already told LINQ about the __type__ of `sa`. But when you do a JOIN, you (generally) select columns belonging to different tables, and therefore the resulting __rows__ are not of a particular type. Therefore LINQ creates a new type on the fly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just like SQL, LINQ also supports JOINs. You can read more about their syntax [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/bb397908.aspx). You should change your query accordingly to get your results. Instead of spoonfeeding the exact answer, I'm guiding you to a more detailed explanation, as it contains valuable information that will help you in the future too.

Comment: Thanks for that, However, how do I select -only- a few columns, as opposed to selecting all the columns? I tried to do it like in SQL, but it does not work and prompts an error instead.

Comment: See http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/bb397941.aspx. In case of JOINs, you often need to select columns from more than one table (entity), therefore the returned objects are generally of  anonymous type, such as the example you posted above in the EDIT section. However if this kind of objects are used excessively in your code, you may want to create a struct or class for it. Your query will then get slightly modified, i.e. instead of doing `select new { sa.SaleID ...`, you'll do `select new YourClass { sa.SaleID ...`. Hope that helps.